# Deleting file in Intellij without searching on project-structure?

Tags: intellij-idea, delete-file, intellij-14

Lets think I have opened some file (ex: .java) on Intellij explorer window. And suddenly, I want to delete that.

Is there a way to delete that straight away without searching where is that on project-stucture sub window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only 2 things that come to mind are:

**1)** Safe delete - click on the class name and then <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DELETE</kbd>

[image: Safe delete]

**2)** Scroll from source & delete - from the `Project` tool window click the *target icon* to select your source file and then delete it

[image: Scroll from source and delete]

Alternatively you can also configure IJ to always auto-scroll from source:
[image: Autoscroll]